# NullPointerException on SQLite update row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm hoping this is something really basic, that I am just not seeing - but I am wondering why the following statement, which calls a method for updating a client, is causing a NullPointerException at the return line of update method.

If it helps to know, I have inserts and selects that work fine and through debugging I know that the update statement has all three variables stored before executing but never executes.

Method Call

```
public void onSaveButtonClick(View v) {

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    // Create and set fields
    EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Name);
    EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Email);

    name = nameField.toString();
    email = emailField.toString();

    db.updateClient(_id, "Test Name", "Test Email");
    Toast.makeText(PTViewClient.this,"TODO: Save Button Functionality", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Update Client Method throwing the NullPointerException

```
        public boolean updateClient(long clientID, String name, String email) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_CLIENT_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_CLIENT_EMAIL, email);
        return db.update(DATABASE_CLIENTS, args, KEY_CLIENT_ID + "=" + clientID, null) > 0;
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    ... 11 more
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at com.personaltrainer.DBAdapter.updateClient(DBAdapter.java:173)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    at com.personaltrainer.PTViewClient.onSaveButtonClick(PTViewClient.java:124)
05-15 12:47:02.978: E/AndroidRuntime(22110):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I think Your `db` is `null`  and use `nameField.getText().toString();` instead of directly calling `toString()` on Edittext. `toString()` Edittext will give string representation of the Edittext, but not the original text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your database

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();
```

Comment: Classic overlook of simple step! Thanks @Hoan Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Just check db and _id wether they are null-pointers before invoking

```
db.updateClient(_id, "Test Name", "Test Email");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
return db.update(DATABASE_CLIENTS,  KEY_CLIENT_ID + "=" + clientID, null) > 0;
```